# FRED Economic Series IDs

Tags: java

I am trying to use the FRED API to get the economic data. The examples provided on the FRED website uses series Id to get the observations/values for a particular series. I am not able to find where I can find the series IDs. For example, in the below example it is asking for series id to get the data-

```
https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id=GNPCA&api_key=*your_key*
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "I am not able to find where I can find the series IDs"... are you looking for a list with [possible series IDs](https://research.stlouisfed.org/pdl/) on the web, or an API call to give you all possible series IDs you can query for using the FRED API?

Comment: Yes TT, is there a way to get that ?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on FRED API, [fred/category/series](https://research.stlouisfed.org/docs/api/fred/category_series.html), "Get the series in a category."; an example:

```
https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/category/series?category_id=125&api_key=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456
```

Comment: TT, again the same question how to get the category Id ?

Comment: @BigD That's a different question if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you:

```
GET https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/search?search_text=**your+search+query**&api_key=**abc123**&file_type=json&observation_start=2016-03-01&observation_end=2016-03-15
```

This will return JSON data with the series id you are looking for....

```
{
  "realtime_start": "2016-04-06",
  "realtime_end": "2016-04-06",
  "order_by": "search_rank",
  "sort_order": "desc",
  "count": 164,
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 1000,
  "series**s**": [
    {
      "id": "**FEDFUNDS**",
      "realtime_start": "2016-04-06",
      "realtime_end": "2016-04-06",
      "title": "Effective Federal Funds Rate",
------------------  json result intentionally cut off -------------
```

There are different ways to get the series id's and category id's found here:
https://research.stlouisfed.org/docs/api/fred/

Comment: note the "seriess" not spelled correctly on the json result

Comment: FYI, looks like the Json object is cut off at the end (unless that is intended, in which case please ignore).

Answer (score 0):

Just go here [Federal Reserve Economic Data | FRED | St. Louis Fed](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/) and search for the series you're interested in.  Alternately, you can browse by several attributes, including Category from there.  Once you've searched, if you find it, click one of the results.  A search for S&P 500 yielded a link to [S&P 500 | FRED | St. Louis Fed](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SP500), which has a chart of it.  You'll see some letters and/or numbers in parentheses right beside the page's title.  In this case, it is SP500.  THAT is your series ID.

Your complete link will be [https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id=SP500&file_type=json&api_key=YourAPIKey](https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id=SP500&file_type=json&api_key=YouAPIKey).  More parameters are here: [St. Louis Fed Web Services: fred/series/observations](https://research.stlouisfed.org/docs/api/fred/series_observations.html)